# Can I configure the Task Queue used by the delay package via queue.yaml?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

It's actually all in the subject: When using Go's very convenient delay package, can I still upload a queue.yaml file and configure the limits etc. for the "built-in" queue? If so, is the queue name simply "delay"? Do any other restrictions apply?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this myself, but [this page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) says:

> The default queue is preconfigured with a throughput rate of 5 task
>   invocations per second. If you want to change the preconfigured
>   settings, simply define a queue named default in queue.yaml.